# Creating Drop-Down Menu For Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a Wordpress theme from scratch. The drop down menu isn't appearing, although I added the list pages tag. Here is the code I'm using for the wp_nav_menu function.

```
 <?php wp_head(); ?>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pull-left">
      <li class="cursive"><a href="#">Mu Alpha Theta</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Menu' )); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The pages appear on the site's menu; however, they aren't merging into a drop-down. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the CSS. As in, do I have to create a structure for how it would look? Or, I'm thinking that I'm misusing th wordpress function.

Thank you for reading my questions. I would love to hear any advice.

Answer (score 2):

If it's placing, but not as you want (in a drop down) it would seem to be a css issue. There are many arguments you can parse to the function outlined [here in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). From there it's just using the id's/classes and css to get the display you're looking for.

Also, from that codex page:

> **Note:** As of 3.5, if there are no menu items, no HTML markup will be
>   output.

So ensure there is some items in your menu as well, even for testing.

Depending on how fancy you want to be, you may need a custom [Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker). *Caveat emptor:* they are not for the faint of heart.